# Looping and index issue

Tags: python

```
mountains = [["Whitney",    4412, 36.578, -118.292],
             ["Williamson", 4384, 36.656, -118.311],
             ["Sill",       4312, 37.096, -118.504],
             ["Shasta",     4303, 41.409, -122.195],
             ["Russell",    4281, 36.590, -118.291]]
def printAllMountains(mntlist):
    for mountain in mntlist:
        printRow(mountain)
        print()
def printRow(row):
    for item in row:
        print(item, "   ", end="")

printAllMountains(mountains)

def findMountain(name, mtnlist):
    for mountain in mtnlist:
        if name == mountain[0]:
            return mountain
```

Why is the `if name == mountain[0]:` at 0? Wouldn't that mean at index 0?

Does this have to do with iteration?

Comment: You have a list of lists. What is the first element of each nested list? The name. Hence why you compare name to the first element in each sublist. There is no issue.

Comment: Where do you call findMountain?

Comment: It was just a question, not about if it's called or not, Donkey Kong answered it , I totally spaced the nested part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for mountain in mtnlist:` Here you are iterating over a list of lists - we'll call them sub-lists

`if name == mountain[0]:` And here you are checking if the name supplied (when the function is called) is the name in the sub-list and now if the condition is true we `return mountain` (the sub-list).

So to wrap it up we're comparing the name supplied to the function when we call it and the name in the sub-list at index 0 in the list `mntlist`